# Why is my update statement not updating the table?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, sql-update

It compiles, it seems to run, but the record is not changed.

Here's my code:

```
private void UpdateRecord(string ATicketID, string ATicketSource, string AContactsEmail, string AAboutSomeID, string ACategoryID)
{
    try
    {
        con = new OracleConnection(oradb);
        con.Open();

        String query = "UPDATE ABC.CONCERTTICKETS SET TICKETSOURCE = :p_TICKETSOURCE, ABOUTSOMEID = :p_ABOUTSOMEID, CATEGORYID = :p_CATEGORYID, CONTACTEMAIL = :p_CONTACTEMAIL WHERE TICKETID = :p_TICKETID";

        cmd = new OracleCommand(query, con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        OracleParameter p_TICKETID =
            new OracleParameter("p_TICKETID", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, ParameterDirection.Input);
        p_TICKETID.Size = 20;
        p_TICKETID.Value = ATicketID;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p_TICKETID);

        OracleParameter p_TICKETSOURCE =
            new OracleParameter("p_TICKETSOURCE", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, ParameterDirection.Input);
        p_TICKETSOURCE.Size = 20;
        p_TICKETSOURCE.Value = ATicketSource;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p_TICKETSOURCE);

        OracleParameter p_ABOUTSOMEID =
            new OracleParameter("p_ABOUTSOMEID", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input);
        p_ABOUTSOMEID.Value = AAboutSOMEID;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p_ABOUTSOMEID);

        OracleParameter p_CATEGORYID =
            new OracleParameter("p_CATEGORYID", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input);
        p_CATEGORYID.Value = ACategoryID;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p_CATEGORYID);

        OracleParameter p_CONTACTEMAIL =
            new OracleParameter("p_CONTACTEMAIL", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, ParameterDirection.Input);
        p_CONTACTEMAIL.Size = 100;
        p_CONTACTEMAIL.Value = AContactsEmail;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p_CONTACTEMAIL);

        try
        {
            try
            {
                ot = con.BeginTransaction();
                cmd.Transaction = ot;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                ot.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                ot.Rollback();
            }
        }
        catch (OracleException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Apparent success");
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
    }

    dataGridView1.Refresh();
}
```

=========
Updated:

So you mean like so, I take it:

```
try
                {
                    using (var transaction = con.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    cmd.Transaction = transaction;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    transaction.Commit();
                } 
                }                
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ot.Rollback();
                    throw;
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Apparent success");
```

===========
Updated yet again (this code works):

```
private void UpdateRecord(string ATicketID, string ATicketSource, string AContactsEmail, string AAboutSomeID, string ACategoryID)
{
    try
    {
        con = new OracleConnection(oradb);
        con.Open();

        String update = @"UPDATE ABC.CONCERTTICKETS 
                          SET TICKETSOURCE = :p_TICKETSOURCE, 
                          ABOUTSOMEID = :p_ABOUTSOMEID, 
                          CATEGORYID = :p_CATEGORYID, 
                          CONTACTEMAIL = :p_CONTACTEMAIL 
                          WHERE TICKETID = :p_TICKETID";

        cmd = new OracleCommand(update, con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        // TICKETSOURCE, ABOUTLLSID, CATEGORYID, CONTACTEMAIL, TICKETID
        OracleParameter p_TICKETSOURCE =
            new OracleParameter("p_TICKETSOURCE", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, ParameterDirection.Input);
        p_TICKETSOURCE.Size = 20;
        p_TICKETSOURCE.Value = ATicketSource;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p_TICKETSOURCE);

        OracleParameter p_ABOUTSOMEID =
            new OracleParameter("p_ABOUTSOMEID", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input);
        p_ABOUTSOMEID.Value = AAboutSOMEID;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p_ABOUTSOMEID);

        OracleParameter p_CATEGORYID =
            new OracleParameter("p_CATEGORYID", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input);
        p_CATEGORYID.Value = ACategoryID;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p_CATEGORYID);

        OracleParameter p_CONTACTEMAIL =
            new OracleParameter("p_CONTACTEMAIL", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, ParameterDirection.Input);
        p_CONTACTEMAIL.Size = 100;
        p_CONTACTEMAIL.Value = AContactsEmail;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p_CONTACTEMAIL);

        OracleParameter p_TICKETID =
            new OracleParameter("p_TICKETID", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, ParameterDirection.Input);
        p_TICKETID.Size = 20;
        p_TICKETID.Value = ATicketID;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p_TICKETID);

        using (var transaction = con.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                cmd.Transaction = transaction;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
                throw;
            }
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Apparent success");
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
    }
    Popul8TheGrid();
}
```

Comment: your outer try block is useless.  you are catching Exception in your inner try.

Comment: It's probably being rolled back but you're not doing anything w/ the exception in that `catch` block so you'd never know it.

Comment: I removed the outer try block; I stepped through it, and the Rollback is not reached. It executes, commits, and shows the "success" msg, but the table is not affected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I note that you really don't have a way to distinguish whether or not an exception was thrown and the transaction was rolled back or if the transaction succeeded. See, you're catching the exception, rolling the transaction back, and then still displaying the message box "Apparent success." because you're swallowing the exception and falling through. There's a reason that [people scream from the top of rooftops to not swallow exceptions](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2007/04/30/swallowing-exceptions-is-hazardous-to-your-health/).

So, I suspect an exception is being thrown, you're catching it, rolling back, and then getting confused because you fall through and show the message box. This is badly written code, and badly written code introduces bugs like this.

At a minimum, I'd rethrow the exception if I were you.

```
catch (Exception) {
    ot.Rollback();
    throw;
}
```

But even better, just wrap the usage of the transaction in a `using` block

```
using(var transaction = con.BeginTransaction()) {
    cmd.Transaction = transaction;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

> Why is my update statement not updating the table?

You have a bug in your code. One of these statements

```
ot = con.BeginTransaction();
cmd.Transaction = ot;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
ot.Commit();
```

is throwing an exception but you don't know it because you're swallowing all exceptions. Stop swallowing the exceptions, and you'll find out which of these lines is throwing an exception and why. Then you'll have more information with which to debug your underlying issue.

Comment: No, stepping through it, it runs fine, and never reaches the catch block.

Comment: I updated my post with what I think you're recommending as far as the BeginTransaction..Commit block.

Comment: No, that is not what I meant. Lose the outer `try/catch`.

Comment: I did delete the outer try/catch, in response to c0deNinja.

Comment: OK, it's working now. I don't know if it was the rearranging of the parameters to put them in the same order as the SQL statement or the rearranging of the try..catch block that got it to working. I updated the post by appending the working code.

Answer (score 6):

Your try/catch blocks are completely broken.

You must fix that first, then you will be able to see what the real error is.

```
try
{
    ot = con.BeginTransaction();
    cmd.Transaction = ot;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    ot.Commit();
    MessageBox.Show("Success"); // <-- this should be here, not after the catch!
}
catch (Exception)
{
    ot.Rollback();
    throw;   // <-- this is important otherwise the exception is swallowed!
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that; I changed my code to add the "throw"; however, Rollback is not being reached.

Answer (score 3):

This code rolls back the transaction without informing the user.

```
   catch (Exception)
   {
       ot.Rollback();
   }
```